# What's this novel? A mathematician turned marine is transported to the future

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read this novel some time in the 90s, not sure when it was written.

The time travel had to happen at certain times, the interface of air and water, early morning. I think in the backstory he had precalculated an interface and stepped through it.

The story is set in or near the Shenandoah Valley. The protaganist keeps his mathematical history quiet and acts as a military support for someone, perhaps a woman, who flies a helicopter and starts the novel mostly brainwashed by the powers that be. He uses standard US marine tactics, unknown in the new time, to defeat guerilla enemies

Gradually he convinces the helicopter pilot and some others that the history they have known is false, and they all escape together on the helicopter into the South American rainforest ready for a new time travel interface.

Anyone know this book?

Comment: I like the premise of the interface of air and water allowing you to time travel!

Comment: Shot-in-the-dark: Starcruiser Shenandoah series by Roland J. Green?  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_J._Green#Starcruiser_Shenandoah)

Comment: @SammyB nice try! But not the right book assuming the description on the Amazon page is correct :(

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263258/series-of-books-novellas-religious-cult-saved-from-depopulation-also-time-trav (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is *[The Douglas Convolution](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12143)* by [Edward Llewellyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Llewellyn-Thomas).  It was published in 1979 and the cover art had a picture of a man hanging out of a helicopter with a rifle.

[image: cover image]

I too read the book a long time ago.  It's available on Amazon used. I was only able to find the book by using your reference to the Shenandoah Valley, thanks.

Comment: Woohoo! nice one